# What did the study plan of a early 20th century mathematics major look like?

Tags: technology, science, education, mathematics, academics

I am interested in what subjects and activities mathematics major were involved in the beggining of the 20th century. Most subjects mathematics majors study at an intermedium and advanced level now were relatively recently developed (for example, Measure Theory or Modern Logic). How different is an early 20th century mathematics undergraduate from a 21st century mathematics undergraduate?

Comment: While I don't think this is off-topic here, you might get better answers over at [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I just posted the same question on History of Science and Mathematics [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/15378/18358). Nevertheless, it seems History of Science and Mathematics is not a very active Stack Exchange.

Comment: It has an answer over on HSM now.

Comment: @Student2271 - They aren't super active because not a lot of users know about it to ask questions. If you ask them something in their bailiwick though, they are baller.